# Checkbox with Bootstrap Toggle returns null if the input isn't checked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, toggle, togglebutton

I am using [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) for checkboxes and I have this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hasLabel" data-on="With Label" data-off="Without Label" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
```

The problem is that if the input is checked the `request.getParameter("hasLabel")` returns `on`, and if it isn't returns `null`

How can I define that if the checkbox is not checked to return `off`, `false` or sth else?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="checkbox" name="hasLabel" data-on="With Label" data-off="Without Label" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
```

Answer (score 1):

use this script to do something before submit form:

```
    <script>
      $("form").submit(function(){
                if (!$('#my-input').prop('checked')) {
                    $('#my-input').bootstrapToggle('on')
                    $('#my-input').val('off')
                }
            });
    </script>
```